# simple multi language site (two languages, mostly static content)

Tags: multilingual, multi-language

This is my first multi language project and should be very simple. The only dinamic content is for blog, but it doesn't need to be translated.
I thought to take these steps, i would like to have some opinion if I'm doing something wrong

**Templates:**

For the main language:

- /index
- /contatti
- /blog
- etc..

For english language i create the template_group "en"

- en/index
- en/contact
- en/blog

**Global variables/embed templates**

i.e.

- "head_html" and "en_head_html"
- "body" "en_body"
- etc...

Is this correct or i'm doing something wrong? Are there better methods for a simple situation like this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have some guidance from http://www.sidd3.com/multi-language-website-with-expressionengine/

Hope, it would help you.

Comment: Hi @Bhashkar , i've a problem with language_code global variable. Following your guide, i inserted the code at the and of index.php and en/index.php. I created two snippet, one for english language and one for italian, and then inserted them to my template, but it doesn't work

Comment: The snippets are menu_it and menu_en and i inserted them with {menu_{language_code}}

Comment: The {language_code} tag isn't parsing. In the index.php, the language global variables should be always above this line of code: require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter'.EXT; I have updated this instruction within my blog.

Comment: now it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the tips provided in the link Bhashkar provided, I would strongly recommend you have a look at [Low Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-variables) - it's a terrifically powerful add-on that gives you the ability to simultaneously create language-version variables as you create them, which when coupled with the language segment global system variables you'd likely create as directed in the article above, becomes a very fast and efficient way to use a single template to conditionally load language-specific content, both static variables, as well as entries.

Answer (score 2):

Just started a repo on Github for a multilingual text fieldtype I'm working on which could help you out, or at least give you some more options : [Babeltext](https://github.com/pseudoclass/babeltext)

Comment: I looked at this field type. Really seems great.

Comment: Thanks. I just have to incorporate the compatibility with other modules and fieldtypes and I'm probably going to make it available on Devotee.

Comment: That would be great...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my practical approach http://digitalevangelist.net/blog/multi-lingual-expressionengine-practical

I used Freebie and Republic Variables mainly

Answer (score 1):

I used [Publisher add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher) and worked great. Gives you the options to see which entries have a translation in draft or published form when you are in the entry list.

I'm still trying to import a Data Base and relate the entries to their translation, but Brian Litzinger, the developer has been very helpful in answering some previous questions.