# how to set the subdomain in localhost?

Tags: subdomain

I want  **domainname.local/index.php** to **domainname.local/country code (domainname.local/us)** i am use the all do name start with **domainname.local/us/?do=index**

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information as to what you need, also `?do=index` is not ExpressionEngine, so what are you doing to get that?

Multi-language using the method you state has been documented and asked many times. Top questions:

- [Multi Languages](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31337/multi-languages)
- [simple multi language site (two languages, mostly static content)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/simple-multi-language-site-two-languages-mostly-static-content)

View all related questions:

- https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/search?q=multi+language

Articles outside of Stack Exchange:

- http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine
- http://rye.agency/blog/multilingual-sites-with-expressionengine
- http://www.sidd3.com/multi-language-website-with-expressionengine